# Redirect to different "Final confirmation page" based on the form from where the request is submitted

Tags: wffm, exm

I have two WFFM forms.
These forms uses a common custom save action to send a double opt-in email using the Sitecore EXM(**Subscription Confirmation** message).
The double opt-in works fine and I receive an email with a confirmation link. On clicking the confirmation link, my contact is added to the List Manager contact list.

Now, the requirement is that when user fills the Form A and then clicks the confirmation link in the email, he should be redirect to Page A.
Similarly, if user fills the Form B and clicks the confirmation link in the email, he should be redirected to Page B.

Basically, if user is filling the **Webinar Form** for example, then he should be redirected to webinar related page after confirming his email.
Similarly, if user is filling the **Product inquiry form**, then he should be redirected to Product page after confirming his email.

I am working with Sitecore 8.2.2, EXM 3.4 and WFFM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to customize the Final Confirmation Page only for the subscription confirmation you would need to create your own custom `ConfirmSubscription.aspx page`. You can find the page in the EXM folder `\sitecore modules\Web\EXM\`.

If you take a look at the default implementation in the file `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.dll` (Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.sitecore_modules.Web.EXM.ConfirmSubscription) you can modify the Redirect url based on your needs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!ExmContext.IsEcmIdVerified)
   {
      this._logger.LogError("Attempt to access ConfirmSubscription with unverified url: " + this.Request.RawUrl);
   }
   else
   {
      string str = this.Request.QueryString[GlobalSettings.ConfirmSubscriptionQueryStringKey];
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
         this._clientApiService.ConfirmSubscription(new ConfirmSubscriptionMessage()
         {
            ConfirmationKey = str
         });
      string confirmativePageUrl = ExmContext.Message.ManagerRoot.GetConfirmativePageUrl();
      this.Response.Redirect(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(confirmativePageUrl) ? "/" : confirmativePageUrl, false);
  }
}
```

If you want to customize the links that are sent in the email or change the path of the ConfirmSubscription.aspx page you need to override the `SendConfirmationMessage` method from the `SubscriptionManager.cs` class. You can see its implementation in the `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.dll` file:

```
public virtual bool SendConfirmationMessage(Contact contact, Guid recipientListId,
              ManagerRoot managerRoot)
{
   //sitecore implementation
   string url = this._hostnameMappingService.GetPublicUrl(WebUtil.GetServerUrl(), managerRoot) + "/sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/ConfirmSubscription.aspx?" + GlobalSettings.ConfirmSubscriptionQueryStringKey + "=" + this.GetConfirmationKey(recipientListId, this._contactService.GetIdentifier(contact), managerRoot);
   //sitecore implementation
}
```